# How to convert <class str> "binary_string" to <class bytes> b"binary_string"?

Tags: python-3.x

### Question - Find a `convert_func()` that satisfies the following

```
>>> source = '\xe6\x88\x91\xe5\x80\x91'
>>> output = b'\xe6\x88\x91\xe5\x80\x91'  # output = bytes('我們', 'utf8')
>>> assert convert_func(source) == output
```

How to define a function `convert_func` that can convert string from `source` to `output`?

### Relationship between these two strings `source` and `output`

```
>>> type(source)
<class 'str'>
>>> type(output)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> source
'\xe6\x88\x91\xe5\x80\x91'
>>> output
b'\xe6\x88\x91\xe5\x80\x91'
```

The `source` is a `<class str>`, but its content (which is `\xe6\x88\x91\xe5\x80\x91`) comes from its binary format `b'\xe6\x88\x91\xe5\x80\x91'` (which is `output`).

### Method Tried

I tried using `source.encode('utf8')`. But this method only works with ascii characters.

```
>>> convert_func = lambda s: s.encode('utf8')

>>> output = 
>>> source = 'abcde'
>>> output = b'abcde'  # output = bytes('abcde', 'utf8')
>>> convert_func(source) == output
True

>>> source = '\xe6\x88\x91\xe5\x80\x91'
>>> output = b'\xe6\x88\x91\xe5\x80\x91'
>>> convert_func(source) == output
False
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: How to convert a unicode str to a bytes str, but the content in the unicode str is actually the bytes str's content.